# Repeating tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() from a Python generator, iterating a database

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

I have a panel dataset that I want to do Long short-term memory (LSTM) on it. Dataset comes from a postgreSQL database. My data structure is similar of the following:

[image]

Therefore, my timestep is 4. It is many-to-many LSTM, both my inputs and output are sequences. Input will have shape `[Batch_size, 4, 23]` and output will have shape `[Batch_size, 4, 2]` (I am one-hot encoding).

I am using a Python generator to fetch the rows. I am fetching many (`fetchmany`) where number_of_records is 4 because it corresponds to one particular person.

```
class it_try:
    import passwords_and_paths

    import psycopg2

    def __init__(self, sql, number_of_records):
        self.sql = sql
        self.number_of_records = number_of_records
        self.pgConnectString = "host='/var/run/postgresql' port='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(it_try.passwords_and_paths.database['port'],
                                                                                                               it_try.passwords_and_paths.database['name'],
                                                                                                               it_try.passwords_and_paths.database['user'],
                                                                                                               it_try.passwords_and_paths.database['pass'])
    self.pgConnection=psycopg2.connect(self.pgConnectString)
    self.pgCursor = self.pgConnection.cursor(name='fetch_large_result')
    self.pgCursor.execute(self.sql)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        row = self.pgCursor.fetchmany(self.number_of_records)
        current_obs = []
        for i in row:
            current_obs.append(i)

        features = np.array(current_obs)[:,3:26]
        labels = np.array(current_obs)[:,-1].astype(int)

        return features, labels

    def __del__(self):
        self.pgCursor.close()
```

The shape of the features is `[4,23]` and the shape of labels is `[4,]`. Then I initialise a Dataset from a generator using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` function of Tensorflow. Shapes and data types are defined properly and I am one-hot encoding the labels here, with batching 3 persons at each call.

```
generator = it_try(sql = 'SELECT * FROM public.basetable order by year, customer_id, quarter', number_of_records = 4)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: generator, (tf.float32, tf.int32), (tf.TensorShape([4,23]), tf.TensorShape([4,])))
train_dataset=train_dataset.map(lambda *x:(x[0], tf.cast(tf.one_hot(x[1],2),tf.int32)))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(3)
```

the output is `<BatchDataset shapes: ((?, 4, 23), (?, 4, 2)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>`. So far so good.

I create the iterator and initialize it and I can successfully print the batches (2 batches in this example).

```
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, 
train_dataset.output_shapes)
X, y = iterator.get_next()
training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    for batch in range(2):
        print(sess.run([X,y]))
```

However, when I wanted to pass the training data more than once (number of epochs is 2 in this example), I get an error and of course, it is because I cannot reset my Python and Tensorflow iterators.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for epoch in range(2):
        sess.run(training_init_op)
        for batch in range(2):
            print(sess.run([X,y]))
```

It prints the very first epoch fine but when it is second epoch, I get the error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

UnknownError: IndexError: too many indices for array
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 410, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "<ipython-input-64-e6c5163f3adc>", line 26, in __next__
    features = np.array(current_obs)[:,3:26]

IndexError: too many indices for array


     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT64], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], token="pyfunc_46"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_23 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,4,23], [?,4,2]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator_23)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-213eeaa1c283> in <module>()
      7         sess.run(training_init_op)
      8         for i in range(2):
----> 9             print(sess.run([X,y]))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

UnknownError: IndexError: too many indices for array
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 158, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 410, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "<ipython-input-64-e6c5163f3adc>", line 26, in __next__
    features = np.array(current_obs)[:,3:26]

IndexError: too many indices for array


     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT64], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], token="pyfunc_46"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_23 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,4,23], [?,4,2]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator_23)]]
```

I tried `.repeat(2)` to no avail.

Can any one help me about this? How can I run epochs when I use python iterator, where data is coming from a database?

Comment: could this have something to do with the way you have defined your generator? The error that its throwing looks like an error from numpy, which means that when your sequence runs out and it has to reinitialize from the beginning, its either having problems shape-wise from your data coming from your database, or the generator definition is the problem. I made a simpler prototype and tested your code with repeat(2) and it worked for me.

Comment: I solved the problem recently. The problem was exactly what you mentioned. Python iterator needed to scroll back to beginning before each epoch run. So, adding `self.pgCursor.scroll(0, mode = 'absolute')` solved my problem, so I could use `.repeat(num_epochs)`.

Comment: thats fantastic!